# iPhone 4" view controller in Xcode 6

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode6

I've recently downloaded Xcode 6(official from apple) but when I create a new project, wether I select iPhone or iPad for the device, I get only iPad-sized view controller in my storyboard. How do I fix that? Thanks

Comment: By default the views are using the Inferred option for Size and Orientation of simulated metrics, you can either keep working at this mode for easier support of all screens or switch to the specific screen sizes, although the combination of the latter and size classes options at the bottom of IB is not very clear.

Comment: @A-Live How can I change that to an iPhone size?

Comment: You can set it at the Attributes Inspector for the selected view controller.